# How do i put numpy.float64 data into dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Im having 5 differents dataframes with values like this:

| tanggal | komoditas | harga |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Beras Sembako | 12000 |
| 2 | Beras Sembako | 12000 |
| ... | Beras Sembako | ... |
| 31 | Beras Sembako | 11000 |

(the only difference between each dataframes is on the 'komoditas' columns values is having different names)

Im using this loop to get the mean values for each of 5 dataframes that is used

```
for z in dfs:
for x in tanggal:
    mean = z.loc[z['tanggal'] == x, 'harga'].mean()
    rata = [mean]
    print(rata)
```

dfs contains 5 different sets of dataframes that im trying to get the mean value from.

tanggal is set of range from (1, 31)

after trying to run it. im getting result as numpy.float64 data like this:

[13916.666666666666][13916.666666666666][13895.833333333334] ... [13901.041666666666]

---

Im trying to convert these values into a dataframe using this

```
df_rata = pd.DataFrame(rata, columns =['Harga Rata'])
```

but when i did it only one value showed up like this:

|  | Harga Rata |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 13901.041667 |

when i tried to define *rata* length using

```
len(rata)
```

it only showed result as only 1 value is stored inside the variable.

---

Is there something that i did wrong?

I'm very new to this and still learning, an explanation would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide dataset in text format. It is difficult to reproduce the problem with image. Sample source code to reproduce the problem always helps.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete information, i've updated the question with the sample of the datasets and the results that i got after trying to run it. Thank you!

Comment: Each time through your loop you set `rata` to a new list of length 1, and only the last one remains when the loop is finished

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) pointed out the issue in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667526/how-do-i-put-numpy-float64-data-into-dataframe#comment131795139_74667526). The fix is to append `mean` to `rata` in the loop:

```py
rata = []
for z in dfs:
    for x in tanggal:
        mean = z.loc[z['tanggal'] == x, 'harga'].mean()
        rata.append(mean)
```

At this point, `rata` will be a list such that `len(rata) == len(tanggal)*len(dfs)` and the mean of harga across tanggal in the first, second, etc data frame is in `rata[0 : len(tanggal)]`,  `rata[len(tanggal) : 2*len(tanggal)]`, etc respectively.

A side comment, if your data is only a single list (like `rata`), consider using [pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#series) instead.